# Implement Guest Feature/ User in E-commerce App Using Flutter Bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I am trying to build an app similar like of e-commerce app (Amazon) in that app when the user open the app it will not go the login screen instead it will go to home screen. Login screen will only comes if the user is not login in checkout screen by clicking on checkout button. How to do this in bloc? I have researched in the internet but did not got any useful information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the example below maybe will help

- Firebase Login Tutorial with bloc : [here] (https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterfirebaselogintutorial) 
  This tutoriel do what you need, I hope it will help you